# recursive loop detected in vars file

Tags: ansible

I have a vars file like this (`vars/apps.yml`):

```
apps:
  app1:
    some_var: hello
    greeting:
      dev: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} world!"
      prod: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} planet earth!"
  app2:
    some_var: hi
    greeting:
      dev: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} world!"
      prod: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} planet mars!"
```

When I execute my playbook with var `app_name=app1`, I get a `recursive loop detected` error.

How would one solve this issue while keeping the `vars.yml` DRY?

Answer (score 0):

you could try defining the `app.some_var` and `app.greeting` variables to different trees, see below:

`hosts`:

```
[test_group]
rhel-green  app_name=app1
rhel-blue   app_name=app2
```

variables file `group_vars/all/test_role.yml`:

```
apps:
  app1:
    some_var: hello
  app2:
    some_var: hi

app_greeting:
  app1:
    greeting:
      dev: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} world!"
      prod: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} planet earth!"
  app2:
    greeting:
      dev: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} world!"
      prod: "{{apps[app_name].some_var}} planet mars!"
```

playbook role `test_role/tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
# tasks file for test_role

- debug:
    var: app_greeting[app_name]
```

output:

```
[root@ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook -i hosts recursive_vars.yml

PLAY [test_group] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel-blue]
ok: [rhel-green]

TASK [test_role : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel-green] => {
    "app_greeting[app_name]": {
        "greeting": {
            "dev": "hello world!", 
            "prod": "hello planet earth!"
        }
    }
}
ok: [rhel-blue] => {
    "app_greeting[app_name]": {
        "greeting": {
            "dev": "hi world!", 
            "prod": "hi planet mars!"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rhel-blue                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
rhel-green                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@ansible ILIAS]#
```